# Draw line around mesh with defined width at cut plane

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I want to display a solid line around mesh with a defined width at a cut plane. Currently I realized that using the same method as `gl_ClipDistance` works using `dot()` operation. However, the output is not what I want since the line width changes depending on angle between the current triangle and the plane. There are also some bad aliasing effects. My guess is that the `abs(factor) < 0.1` is wrong here but I also dont know any other alternative. I'm fairly new to shaders...

How can I solve that issue?

Current output:

[image: Shader output]

It should look similar to that output:
[image: Desired output]

Fragment-Shader:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 fragColor;

in vec3 Normal;
in vec3 FragPos;

uniform vec4 clipPlane0;

void main() {
  float factor = dot(vec4(FragPos, 1.0), clipPlane0);
  if (abs(factor) < 0.1) {
    fragColor.rgb = vec3(1, 0, 0);
  } else {
    fragColor.rgb = vec3(0, 1, 0);
  }
}
```